# Difference between FreeBSD 8.0 CD and DVD

Tags: freebsd

What is the difference between the Installation Media for FreeBSD 8.0. One is a CD and the other is the DVD...any place where I can find what packages are not present in the CD media that are in the DVD media.

Answer (score 3):

The subsequent install disks for FreeBSD contain 'as many third party packages as would fit on the disk'.

The DVD appears to be the first CD + those packages, bundled together.

It's odd that the 8.0 FreeBSD release doesn't include any additional CD images. The previous releases do.

There's some mention here: http://www.freebsd.org/releases/8.0R/announce.html

From the page:

---

**dvd1**

This contains everything necessary to install the base FreeBSD operating system, a collection of pre-built packages, and the documentation. It also supports booting into a "livefs" based rescue mode. This should be all you need if you can burn and use DVD-sized media.

**disc1**

This contains the base FreeBSD operating system and the documentation packages for CDROM-sized media. There are no other packages.

---

Looking back to the release candidate for 8.0, I found the following info:

*"ISO images for all supported architectures are available on the FTP
sites, and a "memory stick" image is available for amd64/i386
architectures.  For amd64/i386 architectures the cdrom and memstick
images include the documentation packages this time but no other
packages.  The DVD image includes a rough pass at what packages will be
available on the official release media but is subject to change between
now and release."*

http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-stable/2009-September/052024.html

Since 8.0 was only recently released, it is possible the additional disks will be released soon.

The disks appear to be available already for PowerPC and ia64 builds.

Comment: Thanks for the input Chris. 

Was just wondering if they had X as part of the disk1 cdrom image.

Answer (score -1):

@Billamama: No, X is not part of disc1 for 8.0-RELEASE.  I just loopback-mounted the ISO image and the `packages/All` directory contains the documentation ports and various translations of the docs:

```
bn-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
da-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
de-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
el-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
en-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
es-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
fr-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
hu-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
it-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
ja-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
mn-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
nl-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
pl-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
pt-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
ru-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
sr-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
tr-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
zh_cn-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
zh_tw-freebsd-doc-20090913.tbz
```

So if you want to install Xorg during the install process, you will have to download either the DVD version or more CD-ROM images from the "disc*[2-N]*" set.